# List<T>.ToList() Not Returning Results

Tags: c#

I have an ASP.NET MVC model that I'm working on which contains a property for a List. The code example is below.

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<Bar> _myList;

    public List<Bar> MyFilteredList
    {
        get
        {
            return _myList;
        }
        set
        {
            _myList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I call this property from my view the list come through great and displays. The problem comes when I want to implement a construct to eliminate all Foo's in the list based on an ID property within them.

I was working on implementing an IEqualityComparer to do that however was running into problems so I greatly simplified my code to at least try to get it working. In doing so I got to the point where simply putting the following get returns no results.

```
get
{
    return _myList.ToList();
}
```

I have a feeling this has something to do with references but I can't quite put my finger on whats going on here. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you should post the code you use to filter the list - it's probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Does it work on the initial request, but fail on the postback?

Comment: @Remus, the OP states that he is not filtering the list anymore -- hence the additional confusion.

Comment: Kirk is right; this usually happens on postbacks, since you probably haven't loaded _myList on the postback with the same data.

Comment: @Kirk When the model is passed to the view that property returns no data. I don't think this is related to MVC as much as something with C#. I also have the feeling it is an "oh damn that was stupid" answer :P

Comment: @Mike, what is the code that assigns to this property?  Also, to confirm, you are seeing this problem on the initial GET?

Comment: @Kirk I think you might have shed some light on the problem with your question. The code that sets the property calls the get to see if the Foo object already exists and then assigns it accordingly. The means that each set also calls a get which with the ToList() call returns a new list. I think the way the other code is working is that the setter is actually writing to the ToList() list so _myList is never actually added to. If this turns out to be the case then yes indeed it was my brain fart of the day. Thanks Kirk.

Answer (score 0):

Going from what @Remus said...

Assuming I had a Class TUser...then I would Overide the Equals

```
Public Overloads Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
            If obj Is Nothing Or Not Me.GetType() Is obj.GetType() Then
                Return False
            End If
            Dim u As User = CType(obj, TUser)
            Return Me.UserId = u.UserId
End Function
```

That way I can or drop a LINQ filter

```
If _myList.Contains(User) Then

End If
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28VS.71%29.aspx) is a reference

Sorry about the VB...